# How to use Comparable to order a prioritylist of objects?

Tags: java, comparable

Here is my object class. There are no errors here.

```
public class AStarNode implements Comparable<AStarNode> {
    AStarNode pathParent;
    int x;
    int y;
    int costFromStart;
    int estimatedCostToGoal;

    public int getCost() {
        return costFromStart + estimatedCostToGoal;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(AStarNode node) {
        int otherValue = node.getCost();
        int thisValue = this.getCost();
        if(thisValue-otherValue > 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is something I have within my AStarSearch class. I'm getting errors here and I'm not sure what to do to fix them. I've been trying stuff for the past hour. What I'm trying to do is have a special method for PriorityList which adds the object somewhere into the PriorityList based on one of the objects variables. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

```
public class PriorityList extends LinkedList {
    public void add(Comparable node) {
        for (int i=0; i<size(); i++) {
            ￼￼￼if(node.compareTo(node) == 0) {
                add(i, node);
                return; 
            }
        }
        addLast(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: `￼￼￼` - what should that be?

Comment: i don't understand your comment

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/3V0hKYY.png

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you asking what the if statement is for?

Comment: No, I'm asking what these chars before it are for

Comment: i don't see those slashes on my screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63561/discussion-between-user3245760-and-msrd0).

Comment: There was something there which I wasn't able to see on this computer for whatever reason. It doesn't show any error now

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation violates the contract of Comparable.

Let's say A's value is 2 and B's value is 1.

If you compare A to B, you'll have 2 - 1 > 0, and you'll thus return 1, meaning that A is bigger than B.

If you compare B to A, you'll have 1 - 2 < 0, and you'll thus return 0, meaning that A is equal to B.

Given this error, any algorithm relying on your comparator will lead to undetermined behavior.

Comment: But it works for my code, no? If I use compareTo and "this" is equal to or less than the index at i, then I can simply insert into that location and keep the correct priority ordering. Else I look at the next index in the list.

Comment: Do I even need to use comparable? Should I just write a method that does what I want?